# ProgressDialog should not be cancelable

Tags: android, progressdialog

I do some database saving that takes few seconds. In the meantime, I want to display my ProgressDialog to show that the app is working on it.

```
    class CreateNewSaves extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activityContext);
            pDialog.setMessage(activityContext.getString(R.string.upload_message));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.show();
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }
        /**
         * Creating saves
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            //Some work done
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

I don't want this ProgressDialog to be cancelable, therefore, I do

```
    setCancelable(false);
    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

But the ProgressDialog is still canceled when touching screen or back button.
I'm not sure if it is hidden or dismissed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        pDialog.show(); // this line should be at last. show will create your dialog, rest values will have no impact.

        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

replce with

```
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);     
            pDialog.show();
```

Comment: That's the way I first tried. However, putting it back to that way then doing a project rebuild worked. Is it normal to have to rebuild project to apply changes sometimes? (I guess this project rebuild helped to consider the setCancelable and setCanceledOnTouchOutside changes)

Comment: if android no need rebuild, run the project. its should reflect in app. else kill app run once again, last choice which will work definately uninstall and install app.

Comment: It sometimes happens that changes are not applied when I stop debugging and launch app in debug mode again. I can see that when app stops on a breackpoint on an empty line - where there was something before changes.